# Required Nothing error while defining null local variable and setting it later in method

Tags: android, kotlin

I have defined variable which is null but later on based on view.tag object type i have to set it.But it say `Required Nothing found RequestCenterDetails`. Below is how i am trying to do this

```
 holder?.addressIcon?.setOnClickListener {

        val tagObject = holder.institutecardView.getTag(R.id.item_institute_cardview)
        var center=null

        if(tagObject is RequestCenterDetails)
        {
            Log.d("location","-------------TEST----------- its a RequestCenter")
            center=tagObject as RequestCenterDetails // over here it say "Required Nothing found RequestCenterDetails"
        }
        else if(tagObject is Center)
        {
            Log.d("location","-------------TEST----------- its a Center")
        }
```

Problem is that i have to take same action based on there field value but both object has different field names. Is there any better way to do this. I am new to kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know `center` will be `RequestCenterDetails`, do

```
var center: RequestCenterDetails? = null
```

If `center` can also be of another type, do

```
 var center: Any? = null
```

A more concise version of what you're doing would be:

```
var center: RequestCenterdetails? = tagObject as? RequestCenterDetails
```

which assigns center the value of `tagObject` if `tagObject` is `RequestRecenterDetails`, else assigns it `null`.

Comment: For completeness: Null variable without explicit type declaration will implicitly assume type `Nothing?` which can only be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that your variable `center` has the type `Nothing?`.
You can change this by saying:

```
var center: Any? = null
```

But this is not advisable to work with such a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify type as it's not clear to the compiler, I'd recommend you to put the highest possible common possible type in hierarchy(for both `RequestCenterDetails` and `Center`) , or just `Any` if you're okay to accept any type:

`var center: Any = null`

or

`var center: CommonBaseClass = null`